# Looping using Hiveql

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to merge 2 datasets, say A and B. The dataset A has a variable "Flag" which takes 2 values. Rather than jut merging both data together I was trying to merge 2 datasets based on "flag" variable.

The merging code is the following:

```
create table new_data as
select a.*,b.y
from A as a left join B as b
on a.x=b.x
```

Since I'm running Hive code through CLI, I'm calling this through the following command

```
hive -f new_data.hql
```

The looping part of the code I'm calling to merge data based on "Flag" variable is the following:

```
for flag in 1 2;
do
  hive -hivevar flag=$flag -f new_data.hql
done
```

I put the above code in another ".hql" file asn calling it:

```
hive -f loop_data.hql
```

But it's throwing error.

> cannot recognize input near 'for' 'flag' 'in'

Can anybody please tell me where I'm making mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: The looping code is not a hive query/script. Hive -f can only run hive queries. Use the looping in a shell script .

Comment: @KSNidhin: Thanks a lot for the comment. I'm running the hive code through putty. Could you please explain what do you mean by shell script? I'm technologically bit novice.

Comment: the flag variable has 2 values 1 and 2 right ?Which is a filter criteria in the hive query right ?.

Comment: @KSNidhin: You are right. Flag has 2 variable and it is the filter criteria. The idea is break the data by flag and merge the data for each of these partition.

Comment: then you could add the filter criteria in the hive query and do the merging in the query itself and then run the query using hive -f <> alone.

Comment: @KSNidhin: Could you please tell me how? It will be great help if you explain it using my toy example. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You should be adding the loop logic to shell script.

**File Name: loop_data.sh**

```
for flag in 1 2;
do
  hive -hivevar flag=$flag -f new_data.hql
done
```

And execute the script like:

```
sh loop_data.sh
```

2. In your new_data.hql script, you are creating table. Since you should split out the DDL & DML in 2 separate scripts. Like

**DDL: create_new_data.hql**

```
create table new_data as
select 
  a.*,
  b.y
from 
  A as a left join 
  B as b on 
  a.x = b.x
where 
  1 = 0;
```

**DML: insert_new_data.hql**

```
insert into new_data 
select 
  a.*,
  b.y
from 
  A as a left join 
  B as b on 
  a.x = b.x
where
  flag = ${hiveconf:flag}
```

And update you shell script like:

**File Name: loop_new_data.sh**

```
# Create table
hive -f create_new_data.hql

# Insert data
for flag in 1 2;
do
  hive -hiveconf flag=$flag -f insert_new_data.hql
done
```

And execute it like:

```
sh loop_new_data.sh
```

Let me know if you want more info.

Comment: Thanks Ambish for your reply!

Comment: how can i used it from hive shell

Comment: @sahildesai please elaborate your question.

Comment: the above solution is for command line but i am using hive queries on hive shell

Comment: Although @Beta 's problem has been solved, still the topic has no answer: how to loop in hive? not from shell but directly in hive?