# Looping in hive query

Tags: loops, hive

I want to create a loop in Hive using for,while but not able to do so.I tried creating procedure but keywords like DO,DECLARE,LOOP are not supported

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping using Hiveql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625826/looping-using-hiveql)

Comment: Can it be done at the query level itself and not using shell.

Comment: No you have to use script for looping.